# What is the best approach to guarantee commits in Apache SOLR?

Tags: solr, solr4, solrcloud

**Question:** How can I get "guarantee commits" with Apache SOLR where persisting data to disk and visibility are both equally important ?

**Background:** We have a website which requires high end search functionality for machine learning and also requires guaranteed commit for financial transaction. We just want to SOLR as our only datastore to keep things simple and **do not** want to use another database on the side.

I can't seem to find any answer to this question. The simplest solution for a financial transaction seems to be to periodically query SOLR for the record after it has been persisted but this can have longer wait time or is there a better solution ?

Can anyone please suggest a solution for achieving "guaranteed commits" with SOLR ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you were told on the mailing list, Solr does not have transactions.  If you index from a dozen clients, and a commit happens from somewhere (either autoSoftCommit, commitWithin on the udpate request, or an explicit commit from one of those dozen clients), *all* of the documents indexed by those dozen clients will be visible to all searchers.

With a transactional database, each of the dozen clients that is sending updates would have to issue a commit, which would only make the changes made by that specific client visible.

Solr usually does not make any guarantees regarding commits.  If you issue ten commits in parallel, that will most likely exceed the maxWarmingSearchers configuration, which is typically set to 2.  Most of those ten commits wouldn't actually create a new searcher, which is what makes new documents visible.

If you do manual commits in such a way that you are never exceeding maxWarmingSearchers, then when that commit finishes without error, you can take that as a sign that all changes are now visible.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is that Solr is **not** designed to be the primary data store. Its data structures and indexing/retrieval designed for other use cases, even if it all seems like CRUD on the surface. You should have your data persisted somewhere else and then indexed in Solr - in the way that makes it easy to find - later. Same with Elasticsearch and other search-oriented software.

If you absolutely have to combine those things, look at the commercial products that included Solr on top of Cassandra or other similar databases.

Comment: My question was on how to guarantee commits in SOLR and not if SOLR is meant for primary or not. MongoDB also does not guarantee commits but two phase commits and mongos log files can be used to somewhat guarantee commit. SOLR can totally be used as a primary data store ... Guardian.uk is using it as a primary db. If you see some presentation by the founders of SOLR .. You can see that they recommend SOLR to be used as a datastore competing NoSql databases.

Comment: I think "recommend" is too strong a word there.  It is widely acknowledged that Solr *will* work for some NoSQL data needs ... but as people keep telling you, it is at its heart a search engine, not a database.  The kind of guarantees that are required for financial transactions simply cannot be made by Solr.

Answer (score 1):

Solr provides two type of commits to persist the data in solr.

- **Soft Commit:** The soft commits persists the into Solr data structure. Solr guarantees visibility of the document after every soft commit. It does not actually stores the data into disk. So if the Solr instance goes down then this information can not be recovered.
- **Hard Commit:** Every time application index the data to solr, it can perform the hard commit of the data. The hard commit persists the data into disk and it recoverable even the instance goes down. The disadvantage of frequent hard commit is, solr has to perform segment merges frequently, which is CPU intensive.

You can configure the autoCommit option in solrconfig.xml according to your needs.

```
<autoCommit>
  <maxDocs>10000</maxDocs>
  <maxTime>1000</maxTime>
  <openSearcher>false</openSearcher>
</autoCommit>
```

There are merits and demerits of each approach. You can find more information on [Apache Wiki Commits](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Near+Real+Time+Searching) and an article from LucidWorks on commits in CloudSolr [Understanding Transaction Logs, Soft Commit and Commit in SolrCloud](http://lucidworks.com/blog/understanding-transaction-logs-softcommit-and-commit-in-sorlcloud/)

Comment: Yes I understand the difference between soft and hard commit but this not answer my question on how to guarantee commits at application layer level. Like how would one process financial transactions with SOLR. I was hoping to get a pattern someone has used to achieve this like the Two phase commit in MongoDB.